# Image URIs with Typescript and React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a very simple application that I am using as a playground at the moment, just playing around in the code and seeing how it all works.

I'm using `tsc` to compile my `.tsx` files into an `artifacts` folder, which is used as the entry point for the compile/gradle.build.

However, I am now trying to include a banner image and have hit a wall. I understand that at the moment my `tsc` won't be doing anything with images, even if i import them, such as `import * as brandImage from '../app/assets/brand.png'`

At this point I'm realising that `tsc` alone might not be enough of a build step. If I wasnt using `typescript` would `react-native` simply move the images I required into a build folder that I could reference?

I'm a touch lost here. I'm assuming I need to move into using something like `babel` to move files over to a `build` or `assets` folder that I can reference in my `.tsx` files.

Does working in `react-native` mean anything for standard assets that I would use to build a react web application? Or do I need to have similar build steps that I usually would use.

Comment: What does the rest of your build process look like? Are you using Webpack or something similar, or are you just calling `tsc` directly? Typescript or no Typescript, you're absolutely right that you need another build step to 1) resolve the imports of your image files appropriately, and 2) get the images into your built code.

Comment: hi @err1100, you are correct, i am just running a `rimraf build` and then `tsc`. What would you recommend? I understand my main options are a) move the files myself using a node package and define it in the script area of the json, b) webpack or c) babel?

Comment: Not quite. Babel is a tool to transform modern Javascript into less modern Javascript that runs in more places. Webpack is a tool to orchestrate various parts of your build process - Babel is usually one of them. Regardless, see my answer for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a React Native project, the story is a little different than for the web. To get a React Native project running on your phone, you eventually have to interact with iOS/Android directly to get your code to run, so spinning up your own build process is not generally recommended. Fortunately, there are plenty of starter projects that allow you to use Typescript with React Native. I would highly recommend checking them out rather than rewriting an entire native build process yourself:

- A simple, bare-bones starter that illustrates how Typescript and RN work together: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Native-Starter
- Another option that is meant to be a drop-in replacement for the normal `create-react-native-app`: https://github.com/mathieudutour/create-react-native-app-typescript

You can also use the [`react-native-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli) to create a new RN app and then add Typescript support yourself:

- https://medium.com/@rintoj/react-native-with-typescript-40355a90a5d7
- https://medium.com/react-native-training/up-and-running-with-react-native-and-typescript-8d398e910a19

Comment: Ah thanks yeah. The main issue I am having is around static resources. At the moment my URI import paths have to point to the files i want to include as if it was in the build folder, instead of relative. I'm guessing thats something that webpack usually takes care of in web but in react-native its a bit more complex. I saw a solution using `package.json` files in the root of the folders i want to relatively point to but I can't manage to get that functioning. Any advice on static resources?

Comment: RN has some documentation around images specifically that might be helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html